# How to enable application insights telemetry correlation

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-application-insights

We have an application which is based on micro services architecture and we have enabled application insights for the application. We have multiple asp.net Web APIs which call each other and also are called from angular based UI. Currently we are able to trace all the telemetry through Operation Id which is constant or same for all telemetry. Till here everything works fine . But next we want to enable hierarchical correlation so that we can know when a Request is triggered what all other requests / dependencies it is triggering  and if there are any exceptions which request caused it .

What I want to know is if this is enabled by default (below I have given my applicationinsghts.config) or is there a step by step guide telling what are the steps we need to follow to enable this kind of correlation.

I have already gone through most of the documentation which is on MSDN and other resources and understand conceptually how it works but I am not able to find a code sample or example which does this for a setup like us.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ApplicationInsights xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ApplicationInsights/2013/Settings">



  <TelemetryConfiguration>

  </TelemetryConfiguration>

<TelemetryInitializers>
<Add Type="ApplicationInsights.OwinExtensions.OperationIdTelemetryInitializer, ApplicationInsights.OwinExtensions"/>
<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector.HttpDependenciesParsingTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.DependencyCollector"/>
<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.AzureRoleEnvironmentTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer"/>
<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.AzureWebAppRoleEnvironmentTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer"/>
<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.BuildInfoConfigComponentVersionTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer"/>
<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.WebTestTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web"/>
<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.SyntheticUserAgentTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web">
<!-- Extended list of bots:
            search|spider|crawl|Bot|Monitor|BrowserMob|BingPreview|PagePeeker|WebThumb|URL2PNG|ZooShot|GomezA|Google SketchUp|Read Later|KTXN|KHTE|Keynote|Pingdom|AlwaysOn|zao|borg|oegp|silk|Xenu|zeal|NING|htdig|lycos|slurp|teoma|voila|yahoo|Sogou|CiBra|Nutch|Java|JNLP|Daumoa|Genieo|ichiro|larbin|pompos|Scrapy|snappy|speedy|vortex|favicon|indexer|Riddler|scooter|scraper|scrubby|WhatWeb|WinHTTP|voyager|archiver|Icarus6j|mogimogi|Netvibes|altavista|charlotte|findlinks|Retreiver|TLSProber|WordPress|wsr-agent|http client|Python-urllib|AppEngine-Google|semanticdiscovery|facebookexternalhit|web/snippet|Google-HTTP-Java-Client-->
<Filters>search|spider|crawl|Bot|Monitor|AlwaysOn</Filters>
</Add>
<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ClientIpHeaderTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web"/>
<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.OperationNameTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web"/>
<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.OperationCorrelationTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web"/>
<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.UserTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web"/>
<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.AuthenticatedUserIdTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web"/>
<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.AccountIdTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web"/>
<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.SessionTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web"/>
</TelemetryInitializers>
<TelemetryModules>
<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector.DependencyTrackingTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.DependencyCollector">
<ExcludeComponentCorrelationHttpHeadersOnDomains>
<!-- 
        Requests to the following hostnames will not be modified by adding correlation headers. 
        This is only applicable if Profiler is installed via either StatusMonitor or Azure Extension.
        Add entries here to exclude additional hostnames.
        NOTE: this configuration will be lost upon NuGet upgrade.
        -->
<Add>core.windows.net</Add>
<Add>core.chinacloudapi.cn</Add>
<Add>core.cloudapi.de</Add>
<Add>core.usgovcloudapi.net</Add>
</ExcludeComponentCorrelationHttpHeadersOnDomains>
</Add>
<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.PerfCounterCollector.PerformanceCollectorModule, Microsoft.AI.PerfCounterCollector">
<!--
      Use the following syntax here to collect additional performance counters:

      <Counters>
        <Add PerformanceCounter="\Process(??APP_WIN32_PROC??)\Handle Count" ReportAs="Process handle count" />
        ...
      </Counters>

      PerformanceCounter must be either \CategoryName(InstanceName)\CounterName or \CategoryName\CounterName

      NOTE: performance counters configuration will be lost upon NuGet upgrade.

      The following placeholders are supported as InstanceName:
        ??APP_WIN32_PROC?? - instance name of the application process  for Win32 counters.
        ??APP_W3SVC_PROC?? - instance name of the application IIS worker process for IIS/ASP.NET counters.
        ??APP_CLR_PROC?? - instance name of the application CLR process for .NET counters.
      -->
</Add>
<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.PerfCounterCollector.QuickPulse.QuickPulseTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.PerfCounterCollector"/>
<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.DeveloperModeWithDebuggerAttachedTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer"/>
<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.UnhandledExceptionTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer"/>
<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.UnobservedExceptionTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer">
<!--</Add>
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.FirstChanceExceptionStatisticsTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer">-->
</Add>
<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.RequestTrackingTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.Web">
<Handlers>
<!-- 
        Add entries here to filter out additional handlers: 

        NOTE: handler configuration will be lost upon NuGet upgrade.
        -->
<Add>System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler</Add>
<Add>Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime.Tracing.RequestDataHttpHandler</Add>
<Add>System.Web.StaticFileHandler</Add>
<Add>System.Web.Handlers.AssemblyResourceLoader</Add>
<Add>System.Web.Optimization.BundleHandler</Add>
<Add>System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory</Add>
<Add>System.Web.Handlers.TraceHandler</Add>
<Add>System.Web.Services.Discovery.DiscoveryRequestHandler</Add>
<Add>System.Web.HttpDebugHandler</Add>
</Handlers>
</Add>
<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ExceptionTrackingTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.Web"/>
<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.AspNetDiagnosticTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.Web"/>
</TelemetryModules>
<TelemetryProcessors>
<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.PerfCounterCollector.QuickPulse.QuickPulseTelemetryProcessor, Microsoft.AI.PerfCounterCollector"/>
<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.AutocollectedMetricsExtractor, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights"/>


<!--<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.AdaptiveSamplingTelemetryProcessor, Microsoft.AI.ServerTelemetryChannel">
<MaxTelemetryItemsPerSecond>5</MaxTelemetryItemsPerSecond>
<ExcludedTypes>Event</ExcludedTypes>
</Add>
<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.AdaptiveSamplingTelemetryProcessor, Microsoft.AI.ServerTelemetryChannel">
<MaxTelemetryItemsPerSecond>5</MaxTelemetryItemsPerSecond>
<IncludedTypes>Event</IncludedTypes>
</Add>-->


</TelemetryProcessors>
<TelemetryChannel Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.ServerTelemetryChannel, Microsoft.AI.ServerTelemetryChannel"/>
<!-- 
    Learn more about Application Insights configuration with ApplicationInsights.config here: 
    http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=513840

    Note: If not present, please add <InstrumentationKey>Your Key</InstrumentationKey> to the top of this file.
  --></ApplicationInsights>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correlation in Application Insights is auto enabled. You should be able to see it working across multiple services. Please provide details if it doesn't work for your apps.

Something like this:

[image]

Comment: Ah...This is exactly what we want but what currently we see is just a flat structure of everything.There are requests,dependencies ,exceptions etc but all are shown in a flat structure and not correlated hierarchically. In our code do we need to explicitly maintain some kind of parent child relationship to achieve this ?

Comment: No, correlation is supposed to light up automatically. You mentioned that you use WebApi - can you please provide more details? Version of .NET, AI SDK. Are both services (which talk to each other) are WebApi? Which version?

Comment: .Net framework 4.6.1,Microsoft.ApplicationInsights 2.4.0.0,Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi 5.2.3. Yes both services are web api and the version are same as mentioned .

Comment: Can you please upgrade to the latest AI SDK (2.6.4 at the time) https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web?

Comment: Great ...awesome.I am able to see the correlation now after upgrading the app insights.Thx.