# Application Insights - Operations that spam multiple application insights?

Tags: azure-application-insights

I have 2 applications and each one of them uses its own application insights. Application Consumer (C) requests data from application Repository (R) via REST/HTTP. I have access on both app insights.

If I investigate C's app map, I can see that it has a dependency on R, but R is displayed the same way any other external (as if I was querying google as far as it knows)

If I investigate R's app map, I can't see any mention of C... as if it didn't exist...

How can I make one application aware of the existence of the other? Isn't this supposed to be like out-of-the-box?

Comment: It should work out-of-the-box. The fist thing to check is whether correlation works.

Comment: how can I check that?

Comment: You can refer to [How to enable application insights telemetry correlation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50763074/how-to-enable-application-insights-telemetry-correlation), [Telemetry correlation in Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/correlation) and [Track custom operations with Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/custom-operations-tracking#outgoing-dependencies-tracking)